# SELinux on RHEL8 with Gunicorn and nginx has problems with saving file into diretory

Tags: nginx, selinux, gunicorn

I have Django application running on RHEL8 via Gunicorn and nginx. All works fine in case of testing with SELinux disabled. When I enable SELinux, there is a problem with saving the picture from Website form i got Server Error (500).

Looking into SEL logs:

audit2why:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1692276970.763:137): avc:  denied  { add_name } for  pid=1022 comm="gunicorn" name="29fda977-925d-490a-bf01-1d57bca5b02d.jpeg" scontext=system_u:system_r:init_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0

        Was caused by:
                Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

                You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.
```

Example context for dir where photo is saved:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 2 user nginx system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 104 Dec  1  2021 photo
```

More logs in /var/log/messages

```
Aug 17 14:56:17 webserver setroubleshoot[2249]: SELinux is preventing gunicorn from add_name access on the directory 29fda977-925d-490a-bf01-1d57bca5b02d.jpeg. For complete SELinux messages run: sealert -l 09af96cb-e073-4d2f-bcb5-8756e98df308
Aug 17 14:56:17 webserver setroubleshoot[2249]: SELinux is preventing gunicorn from add_name access on the directory 29fda977-925d-490a-bf01-1d57bca5b02d.jpeg.#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that gunicorn should be allowed add_name access on the 29fda977-925d-490a-bf01-1d57bca5b02d.jpeg directory by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'gunicorn' --raw | audit2allow -M my-gunicorn#012# semodule -X 300 -i my-gunicorn.pp#012
```

I tried the steps above, but still no luck. What is wrong here? How to debug?